# How to configure ZK form to show browser cache data?

Tags: browser-cache, zk

I am new to ZK framework. As per my requirement, I need to convert JSP-Servlet based application into ZK framework. One requirement is I need to show previously filled data [stored in browser cache] in forms input boxes when user click in that input box or type similar characters.

This was the default behavior in the JSP-Servlet application or any other HTML based GUI. But by default ZK form does not show previously filled data. I tried some googling to find its solution but could not found any. Please provide me the solution for that.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies for that.

Here is a [link to the documentation](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Guide/ZK_in_Depth/Inter_Page,_App_Communication/Use_cookies) of cookies for zk.

Code provided in the link :

```
public void onCookie(){
    try {
        //add cookie
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)Executions.getCurrent().getNativeResponse();
        Cookie userCookie = new Cookie("user", "xxx123");
        response.addCookie(userCookie);

        //get cookie
        Cookie [] cookies = ((HttpServletRequest)Executions.getCurrent().getNativeRequest()).getCookies();
        System.out.println(cookies[0].getName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try and let you know the result.